# How to send text message to more than 1 number?

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to have a list of contact numbers.

I want to know is there a way to send a text message to more than 1 number iprogrammatically in Android?

If so how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this via Intent, as the android SMS app doesn't allow multiple recipients.

You can try using the `SmsManager` class.

First of all you need to request the permission `android.permission.SEND_SMS` in your AndroidManifest.

Then you can do something along these lines.

```
// you need to import the Sms Manager
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

// fetch the Sms Manager
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

// the message
String message = "Hello";

// the phone numbers we want to send to
String numbers[] = {"555123456789", "555987654321"};

for(String number : numbers) {
  sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
}
```

---

Update: Added how to split a comma-separated string

```
// string input by a user
String userInput = "122323,12344221,1323442";

// split it between any commas, stripping whitespace afterwards
String numbers[] = userInput.split(", *");
```

Comment: Also if a user enter's the numbers seperated by commas in a edit text and when they hit send, how would i translate this to String numbers[]?

Comment: Could you add this to the code above? Just use for instance, a user enters 122323,12344221,1323442, and i get the String from the Edit text..How would i convert this to a String numbers[]?

Comment: This code doesn't work .. because your for loop runs faster than message sending process.. so in the loop you are telling `SmsManager` to send sms  while it is busy sending previous sms

Comment: so how to overcome the defect to send sms to multiple number @Praveen

Comment: @KarthickM You have to make sure that previous message was sent before sending another

Comment: @Praveen how can we ensure that previous message is sent or not?

Comment: what are the limits of phone number i mean how many recipient we can add for 1 message ?

Answer (score 8):

for group sms or multiple sms use this

```
  Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.putExtra("address", "987385438; 750313; 971855;84393");
    i.putExtra("sms_body", "Testing you!");
    i.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(i);
//use permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

you can modify this "9873854; 750313; 971855; 84393" with your contact number

Comment: can we send mms  this way? if yes please specify how