# Mass SMS not being sent out to everyone

Tags: java, android

I have a program that sends a pre-defined message depending on what button I push. It worked fine on my old phone (OG Evo) but will only send to the first 14 people on my new one (Evo LTE).

I pulled a LogCat and keep seeing this block of code over and over:

```
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308): null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308): java.lang.RuntimeException: null sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:200)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Looper.quit(Looper.java:245)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.HandlerThread.quit(HandlerThread.java:96)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.htc.usage.service.UsageStatsService.onDestroy(UsageStatsService.java:197)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:2762)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-06 11:25:34.850: W/MessageQueue(28308):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 11:25:35.320: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): @@ iconIndex=1
06-06 11:25:35.320: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): isCdma():true hasService:true mSimState=UNKNOWN gprsState=0 mDataState=2 dataActivity=4 mPhone.htcModemLinkOn:false hspa==true
06-06 11:25:35.330: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): hasService()=true ,mDataState=2 ,mPhone.htcModemLinkOn()=false ,mDataActivity=4
06-06 11:25:35.340: D/PhoneStatusBarPolicy(611): slotType[0]=SIM
06-06 11:25:35.451: V/UsageStatsService(28308): CMD_ID_UPDATE_MESSAGE_USAGE
06-06 11:25:35.471: V/UsageStatsService(28308): MSG_ON_MESSAGE_UPDATE
06-06 11:25:35.501: V/UsageStatsService(28308): MSG_STOP_SERVICE
06-06 11:25:35.501: V/UsageStatsService(28308): onDestroy
```

Complete LogCat: http://pastebin.com/hZXwR5FL

I don't get how the thread is getting closed after 15 people since I am not closing it.

My coding: http://pastebin.com/xe4U4GYZ

Can anyone spot how this thread is getting closed?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bunch of things, like a hard limit set by HTC on the number of messages being sent in a given amount of time.

You can try several thing :

1. Put the loop you have in each clickListener inside a method
2. Put the loop in a new thread via AsyncTask, so that you do not hang the UI
3. Create only one SmsManager and reuse it instead of recreating it for each message you send
4. Try to send the message to several users at once following this idea : [How to send text message to more than 1 number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772588/how-to-send-text-message-to-more-than-1-number)

Good luck